# Formulating and solving box unloading as graph problem

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, computer-science, packing-problem

I have a set of boxes as those pictured below. I can only remove boxes that dosen't have any boxes on top of it. In every "move" I can move any box that is currently available, but I have limitations on how much the boxes can weigh in a single move. The numbers are the boxes weight.

[image: box]

So for example, if my capacity was 4 in the example above, I could have moved both A and E in a single sweep, but if it were 3, I would have had to choose between moving A or E.

I am unsure of how to think about this problem. I was thinking about formulating it as a graph with costs between the nodes corresponding to the weight, and then having a max flow limit. But it would be problematic since if, for example, I do the moves `(A),(BE)` (having 3 as max capacity), the cost between C and D would be 0. But if I would do `(A),D`, it would not be zero.

Any suggestion and pointers?

Comment: Is the goal to remove all the boxes in the fewest number of 'sweeps'?  Also, if your max is $3$, in your given configuration, can you remove A and B in a single sweep? (Or do all moved boxes have to be available at the beginning of the sweep?)

Comment: Yes, it is. And no, they have to be averrable at the beginning of the sweep.